# R: Validate Data for Numeric Variables with Different Length

Tags: r, validation, logical-operators, na

Here's my dataframe

```
Key Q1   Q2   
1    1   NA     
2    2    1   
3    8   NA     
4    3    2   
5    1    32  
6    5    3
```

I would like to validate if the data follows the rules

Rule1:

```
 if Q1==1,  Q2 can only have 1 & 2
```

Rule2:

```
 if Q1!=1, Q2 has to be empty/without any value
```

I would like to  have the results as stated below:

```
 Key Q1   Q2   Result
 1    1   NA   TRUE
 2    2    1   TRUE
 3    8   NA   FALSE
 4    3    2   TRUE
 5    1    32  FALSE
 6    5    3   FALSE
```

However, I got the warning error "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".

Comment: better to add code for the df rather than a screenshot. It really helps

Comment: Also what do you mean  empty/without any value? (in a numeric column "empty" does not exist. NA's are inserted)

Comment: And how did you get `I got the warning error "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".`. Please add your code you tried

Comment: In the first row, Q1 is 1 and Q2 is NA or blank.  So, why is it TRUE?  Your rule is `Q1=1, Q2 can only have 1 & 2`

Comment: Yes, in first and third row, Q2=NA. I'm using the following code if(Q1==2|Q1==3|Q1==5|Q1==8)(Q2==1&Q2==2)

Comment: Add them as edition in the initial question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
 with(df1, (Q1==1) & (Q2 %in% 1:2)|(Q1 != 1 & is.na(Q2)))
```

Comment: I got Result=FALSE in row 1 due to NA in Q1 and Result=FALSE in row 10 due to code 3 in Q2. Can you help?

Comment: @CHONG Do you have NA or `""` in 'Q2'

Comment: I have NA in Q2

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I'm able to get the result by using your code. with(df1, (Q1==1 & is.na(Q2))|(Q1 != 1 & !is.na(Q2)&Q2<=2))